# I want to figure out how to run a query on a very big table(more than 2 billion rows) without crashing MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I want exact index value of a particular date time(non-indexed column).Without running query on the non-index column(date time column) of a very huge table in mysql Database.

Comment: You won't crash the database, but it will be very slow. The best thing to do would be to index the column, or if it's a one-off, to run the query and wait. Can you tell us more about your query and schema?

Comment: why do you mot make also an index on the date. Besides that is not enough information on tge problem and it is hard to understand, what you exactly want

Comment: With 'index value' you mean the primary key? How do you want to find that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to search data to a specific DateTime without searching for that specific DateTime? Or you just dont want to / must not build an index over the DateTime-column?